# how to login to oracle express as a new user

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm getting started with Oracle Express.  I used sqlplus to connect and create a new user then tried to use it with the password I gave it.  Got a login error (tried 3 times with password I set).  I'm surely missing something simple!  What is my problem here?

```
>.\sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Apr 15 14:50:40 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter session set container = xepdb1;

Session altered.

SQL> alter user foo identified by bar
  2  ;

User altered.

SQL> connect foo
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Check contents of `TNSNAMES.ORA`. "My" XE database (the same version as yours) has alias `pdb1`:

```
PDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ods...r)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
```

Then check `SQLNET.ORA`. "My" version looks like this (your should too, I'd say):

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Now, at operating system command prompt:

```
c:\temp>sqlplus scott/tiger@pdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Apr 15 21:04:58 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Apr 15 2022 21:02:33 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Comment: The error message is "invalid username/password; logon denied". What do TNSNAMES.ORA and SQLNET.ORA have to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` is a local user, who exists only in container `xepdb1`, then the `connect` command should be `connect foo@xepdb1`. The `connect` command doesn't check to see where the user may exist (and indeed, different users by the same name may exist in different containers); you must include the container name in the command.

Perhaps you thought that, since you changed the container to `xepdb1` (while connected as `sysdba`) already, the `connect` command would assume "within the same container". It does not.

Comment: aha, makes sense. though when I say `connect foo@xepdb1` it pauses about 30 sec then replies `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified` which I suspect may be a different problem

Answer (score 0):

Succeed with:

```
connect foo/bar@localhost:1521/xepdb1
```